# What additional processes and skills are involved in "Human Experience Design"?

Tags: design, experience, process, skills

It seems that the nature progression of the scope that is being covered by the Human Computer Interaction (HCI) and more recently User Experience (UX) design discipline has extended to "Human Experience Design", which appears to be encompassing not just experiences for users of an application or customer of a company's products and services but for all of humanity (as the term seems to imply).

The popularization of Service Design as a specialization involved broadening the lens of the UX scope from users interacting with an application to customers engaging with all of the company's products and services. It also involves understanding the underlying support processes and systems and requires putting on the business analyst's hat.

My guess is that Human Experience Design would involve investigating some of experiences that are not confined to the commercial or organisational environment, as suggested by some of the definitions provided.

> Human experience looks beyond commercial needs to understand and meet
> human desires such as freedom, identity and creation.

From:

> https://www.ama.org/publications/MarketingNews/Pages/are-you-designing-for-human-experience.aspx

However, this does not feel like it would involve new skills or processes, but may require more focus on issues such as inclusiveness and diversity in design, accessibility, AI, IoT and other emergent technologies.

What are the skills and processes (and artifacts?) associated with Human Experience Design specifically and not found in Service Design (SD), Customer Experience (CX) or User Experience (UX) design?

Comment: Minor request, could you expand the acronyms in the last sentence? assuming SD is service design?

Comment: @dougajmcdonald you are right, the overuse of acronyms in many professional fields is not helping to make things easier to understand for people when communicating ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Management Consultants spend their lives dreaming up - fictional - Hot New Methods which they can write books about (and make money)  This sounds like one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***TLDR;***

- ***Cognition is one of the key parameters to explain users and the idea behind their behaviours with psychoanalysis. As well as the topic is issued under psychology discipline of User Experience (UX), it should be supported with the fact behind that psychology like concrete phenomenons using psychophysical analysis.***
- ***Like the time transitioning from product-oriented vision to user-centered products, more niche specialization on Experience-Centered Design is currently being experienced while the ability to gather and manage all these experiences required to be present in regards to successfully being adapted.***

#### Preface

Cognition is the name of the process how human percieves (can be used with many other words to describe the phases) information. As a default, we pick related information among the nature (consciously or subconsciously) while it's called Natural Information Processing. Sweller (2011) explains this system's compounds as a whole nature has it's own set of paradigms to observe, classify, store, re-call, etc. to grasp that information.

Sweller (1988) describes the elements of natural processing system for humans as affective memory, working memory and long-term memory. And in sake of keeping the issue brief, principles of natural processing systems as follows;

> - Information Store,
> - Borrowing and Re-organizing,
> - Randomness as Genesis,
> - Narrow Limits of Change,
> - Environmental Organizing and Linking

#### Analyze

During the transition from feodality to industrialism, markets are working according to **"Sell What You Can Produce"** principle. With the progress on cognition, Freud (1933) and Neisser (1967)'s cognitive psychology was the new paradigm where industrial products has concrete structure that appealing to human nature which let them understand the full product by their senses. By the time personalization or the user-centered design was hype, it was more related to psychology that why makes people think that way and build an idea around it.

With the era currently being experienced from industrialism to digitalism, the products are all softwares and require set of specific features like Skeuomorphism (basically shadows and offsets) to make it easily distinguishable to their users. And now there's psychophysical analysis which investigates the physically fundamental background besides what its studied within psychology branch under UX. And the marketing strategy was changed to **"Produce What You Can Sell"**

While the first group (industrial) of products can be emphasized by users on default since their concrete structures can be learned by human sense, the latter group (software) products can only be understood only if their designs appealing to human sense (like imitating a play button meaningfully like on a music player on the software interface to make user believe and it should be pressed/clicked).

In fact when the subject is **`Experience`**, namely UX in terms of the name of this StackExchange site, the part that analyzing the human nature is a bit more considered in a psychology even it's mainly affected what's produced as an outcome of a human metabolism as well.

Regardless of any subtopic of this experience, people are tend to behave like considering only the defacto rules like *`Accessibility (a11y)`* and its common web standarts like *`WCAG (Web Content Accessibility Guideline)`*, while disregarding the underlying causes why these rules are consequently gathered. So to be brief, psychological part of the experiences should be more supported by it's naturally physical background whatever the experience is about to being applied.

#### Processes and Skills

Even many may find it irrelevant in terms of UX, the main principles how human get the most out of the software application, relies on the subtle elements where our metabolism, emotion, spritiual, and even astrological mood besides many more situation. From a bit different point of perspective, a group of human being are tend to behave like similar in relatively in same situations. Like buying/selling stocks when a similar pattern observed or like to go on shopping before feasts. Similar approach applies to the sectors where human is the main workforce, to say namely developers are not willingly participate in any design activities and the designers do not even think they can code in a programming role.

Again to be short, psychological consequences triggered by the way body/spirit metabolism behaves like so. For instance, feeling desperate when suffering from extreme thirst may make someone psychologically feel depressive, and put someone in a position where darker colors/themes may seem more tempting and meaningfull just because our body lacking water. Like color contrast, while we taking into account the principles of design, it's obviously because of the human eye's physical constraints even people think like it's canon for all the creatures in the world.

With the paradigm shifts from industrial to digital, supplementary issues behind their design philosophies varies as well while the axis is fluid even foundationally on the users, namely humans. With the first phase of User-Centered Design, there was more of psychologic topics issued during the personalized ads and marketing campaings with the rise of e-trade apps mostly but, nowadays we're experiencing the niche part that makes it going a bit further with implementing the physical facts and constraints behind that psychology cognitively.

During this paradigm shift, UX is also living the potential change as including the physical/metabolismic part of humanity as a background and more likely evolves including not only research and design, but also development (of a prototype with programming). By not means of psycophysical analysis but since the development needs design decisions within the very first phase of it's initialization via deduction.

As it's also preferred omitting plus sign before all the positive numbers, the term **`Human Experience Design`** is a bit seems conceptual name (to me), while it's generally likely to put under the topic of **"Experience Design"**, since everybody reading this philosophy assumed to be humans as well. Besides since the development on web requires setting "robots.txt" for search engine crawlers to be able to have a more proper experience, it might be called **`Robotic/Autonom Experience Design`** someday. So that generally speaking, calling the new phenomenon solely as "Experience Design" topic would be more suitable.

And the question about the processes of the new hype Experience Design is a bit topic of another question since it depends on the experience field's itself like the main idea behind these processes is each of the areas has it's own processes as their fundamentals best fit. Like service design differs for each of the subject area's itself besides developer experience and customer experience fields seperately has a different set of processes and frames to answer the question.

Lastly it worths to mention about the **`Persuasive Technology (PT)`** which Fogg's (2003, 2009b) Behaviour Model puts it where all the experiences you mentioned leading to be directed by the experience designers.

#### Conclusion

> What additional processes and skills are involved in “Human Experience
> Design”?

As responded generally with the previous title, the process are varies according to that type of specefic experience type as mentioned, such as UX (for software), Developer Experience, Customer Experience or what's issued under the roof concept of Experience Design. These different experience types (namely customer, developer, user) needs their own physically/analytically analysed processes as backgrounds besides their psychological side.

Generally speaking, unlike prior approaches like producing products that has software as a part of it via settling **`Product`** and **`Information Technology (IT)`** teams where UX is placed under the roof of one of them, the newer approach requires producing designs that appealing to user that has software via settling seperately **`UX team`** at the same level with product and IT teams as well.

Besides the iterations on the organizational level, the job's itself also evolves like the titles as UX Developer/Engineer roles can be observed from the vacancies, and that being said, UX is more becoming the area where one can have skills like research, design, and prototype with code as if it's the case to evaluate under the roof of one product management.

**References:**

- Fogg, B.J., 2003. Persuasive technology: using computers to change what we think and Do. Morgan Kaufmann.
- Fogg, B.J., 2009b. 'A behavior model for persuasive design'. Proceedings of Persuasive Technology: Fourth International Conference, Persuasive 2009, Claremont, California.
- *Freud, S., 1933. Anxiety and instinctual life. New introductory lectures on psychoanalysis, 22, pp.81-111.*
- *Neisser, U., 1967. Cognitive psychology. Englewood Cliffs: Prentice-Hall. ISBN 978-0131396678.*
- *Sweller, J., 1988. Cognitive load during problem solving: Effects on learning. Cognitive science, 12(2), pp.257-285.*
- *Sweller, J., 2011. Cognitive load theory. In Psychology of learning
  and motivation (Vol. 55, pp. 37-76). Academic Press.*

Comment: +1 This is a well thought-out answer, and some thing that I wasn't quite expecting from the initial question :) I really like the explanation as well as the references, and I hope others will find the answer interesting to read.

Comment: More then happy to hear that especially from you. Moreover I got happier when I discovered it's been more than 2 years since it's asked. I'm having intention to write about a couple of more topics I'm experiencing more than a couple of years hence, your bounty on your own question make me force to bring them together. Thanks to "you" anyway. Will try to edit a bit while maintaining the core idea behind and relate a couple of topics whenever I found a chance.

Comment: Actually, there are lots of questions on UXSE that are still relevant over a period of time. I try to update my questions when more information comes to hand, or when I feel the need to engage the community on them (e.g. questions about ethical design practices). Happy to know that bounties help with drawing attention as intended as well :)

Comment: Unfortunately what you have written is incomprehensible to a native English speaker (which I am).  I would suggest getting some help translating into English.  Your choice of references also doesn't support your argument.  You might benefit from reading this 1977 book. Don Norman has a long history in the field: https://www.abebooks.co.uk/9780124509603/Human-Information-Processing-Introduction-Psychology-0124509606/plp

Comment: Thanks for feedback & suggestion @PhillipW. Even I felt sorry about being grammatically poor and not providing enough argument to support the ideas behind these facts according to you, it's mostly because since it's a bit matter of a relatively new concept for me to make them look properly organized on the paper. Besides granting 2 times IELTS 6.5 - Academic to satisfactorily pursue PhD level cognitive-XR topic in Britain, I saw lots of similar usage of sentence complexity with James Joyce and some other authors.